# Java и изменение сторонних классов

Tags: java, импорт

Захотелось изменить сторонний класс, подключаемый как `import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;` Другими словами, подключение идет из стороннего источника и я никак не могу редактировать его... Если бы мог, я бы тут не сидел...

Появилась идея создать свой класс в проекте, и скопировав туда код исходника, переименовав имена функций и т.п.,  создать  его копию, но, как вы понимаете, ничего не работает )))

Отсюда вопросы:

#### Вопрос 1

В  классе  `Actions` подключаются сторонние библиотеки, соответственно, если класс рабочий, то  подключены все необходимые библиотеки.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.IntConsumer;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.PointerInput.Kind;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.PointerInput.MouseButton;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.PointerInput.Origin;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.MouseAction.Button;
```

Тогда почему компилятор ругается на неизвестные ему классы ?

```
 private final Map<**InputSource, Sequence**> sequences = new HashMap();
    private final **PointerInput** defaultMouse;
    private final **KeyInput** defaultKeyboard;
    private final **Keyboard** jsonKeyboard;
    private final **Mouse** jsonMouse;
    protected **CompositeAction** action;
```

#### Вопрос 2

Если подключить все необходимые библиотеки, то появляется ошибка:

> 'size()' is not public in 'org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence'.
> Cannot be accessed from outside package в функции

```
private Sequence getSequence(InputSource source) {
        Sequence sequence = (Sequence)this.sequences.get(source);
        if (sequence != null) {
            return sequence;
        } else {
            int longest = 0;

            Sequence examining;
            for(Iterator var4 = this.sequences.values().iterator(); var4.hasNext(); longest = Math.max(longest, examining.size())) {
                examining = (Sequence)var4.next();
            }

            sequence = new Sequence(source, longest);
            this.sequences.put(source, sequence);
            return sequence;
        }
    }
```

Если данный метод (`examining.size()`) не является публичным,  то как он работает в классе оригинала?

Answer (score 1):

Онo там работает, потому что они в одном пакете (`package`) и поэтому имеют доступ к элементам друг друга с модификаторoм доступа по умолчанию.

---

Как Вы собираетесь использовать этот копию-класс?

Comment: Теперь все встало на свои места. Спасибо. В  классе  Actions Есть функция  moveByOffset
В ней  есть пауза на действие 200 мс. (return this.tick(this.defaultMouse.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(200L), Origin.pointer(), xOffset, yOffset));) Хотел ее убрать. Переопределить функцию не удалось, поэтому решил скопировать класс целиком. На данный момент, переписал функцию, в которой ошибка, и сейчас все работает.

Comment: @Alex_smith Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я вижу, этот класс не отмечен как `final`. А значит, вы можете создать свой класс, наследоваться от этого класса и переопределить нужные вам методы. В них же вы можете вызывать методы класса-родителя вот так: `super.someMethod()`. Не получится переопределить только те методы, которые `final`.